# Deserialize array with items having variable names

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I need to deserialize the following XML sample, and after trying all day I didn't succeed.

The problem is that the element names are different, even though they refer to the same prototype.

What would be the best approach ?

```
<Test Name="SomeName">
    <OBJECTS NbObjects="2">
        <OBJECT0 ObjectName="ObjName1">
            <COMMAND NbCommand="3">
                <COMMAND0 CommandLabel="Command_A" CommandFileName="File1"/>
                <COMMAND1 CommandLabel="Command_B" CommandFileName="File2"/>
                <COMMAND2 CommandLabel="Command_C" CommandFileName="File3"/>
            </COMMAND>
        </OBJECT0>
        <OBJECT1 ObjectName="ObjName2">
            <COMMAND NbCommand="8">
                <COMMAND0 CommandLabel="MyCommand1" CommandFileName="File1"/>
                <COMMAND1 CommandLabel="MyCommand2" CommandFileName="File2"/>
                <COMMAND2 CommandLabel="MyCommand3" CommandFileName="File3"/>
                <COMMAND3 CommandLabel="MyCommand4" CommandFileName="File4"/>
                <COMMAND4 CommandLabel="MyCommand5" CommandFileName="File5"/>
                <COMMAND5 CommandLabel="MyCommand6" CommandFileName="File6"/>
                <COMMAND6 CommandLabel="MyCommand7" CommandFileName="File7"/>
                <COMMAND7 CommandLabel="MyCommand8" CommandFileName="File8"/>
            </COMMAND>
        </OBJECT1>
    </OBJECTS>
</Test>
```

This is the c# code I am trying with no luck:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XMLtest
{
    [XmlRoot("Test")]
    public class Test
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("OBJECTS")]
        public Objects objects { get; set; }

        public void Load(string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Test));
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                Test test = xs.Deserialize(rd) as Test;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Objects
    {
        [XmlAttribute("NbObjects")]
        public int NbObjects { get; set; }
        [XmlArray]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Object))]
        public List<Object> ObjectList { get; set; }

        public Objects()
        {
            ObjectList = new List<Object>();
        }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ObjectName")]
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("COMMAND")]
        public Commands Cmds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Commands
    {
        [XmlAttribute("NbCommand")]
        public int NbCommand { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("COMMAND")]
        [XmlArrayItem("COMMAND")]
        public List<Command> CommandList { get; set; }

        public Commands()
        {
            CommandList = new List<Command>();
        }
    }

    public class Command
    {
        [XmlAttribute("CommandLabel")]
        public string CommandLabel { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("CommandFileName")]
        public string CommandFileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be not to use `<OBJECT0 ... >`, `<OBJECT1 ... >` or `<COMMAND0 ... >`, `<COMMAND1 ... >` and so on. These are different tags meaning differt items/objects.

If the number is important to you change the items to `<OBJECT id='0' name='...'> ... </OBJECT>` and `<COMMAND id='0' label='...' filename='...' > ... </COMMAND>`. This would give you the ability to sort or identify them by the id and all tags are of the same type.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. But I did not generate this 'bad' XML, and need to parse it. BTW the number of objects go up to 72 ! So i would very much like to avoid having 72 different classes to deserialize this.

Comment: Perhaps you can parse the XML-File with a regular expression and replace `<OBJECT(\d)` by `<OBJECT id='\1'` and `</OBJECT\d>` to `</OBJECT>`. After this the resulting XML-string can be deserialized into your object structure.